# Unity Assembly references missing when installing Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, json.net

I have the problem, where Unity shows me an error "The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found" but my compiler (Visual Studio) has all the assambly references it need and doesent show an error. I can hardly tell how you should be able to reproduce the error. Maybe it occures when you try to install Newtonsoft.Json to a Unity project.

There might be a hint here. When I installed Newtonsoft.Json to my Unity project. Visual Studio lost every single assambly refrence in "Assembly-CSharp.Player". I had to restart my PC and since then the Error appears.

Would be nice if someone has an idea how to fix this. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are Using Unity, check if Newtonsoft.Json is installed via the Window->Package-Manager using `com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.0`